# How to change Tkinter Button state from disabled to normal?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, state

I need to change the state of a `Button` from `DISABLED` to `NORMAL` when some event occurs.

The button is currently created in the DISABLED state using the following code:

```py
self.x = Button(self.dialog, text="Download", state=DISABLED,
                command=self.download).pack(side=LEFT)
```

How can I change the state to `NORMAL`?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You simply have to set the `state` of the your button `self.x` to `normal`:

```
self.x['state'] = 'normal'
```

or

```
self.x.config(state="normal")
```

This code would go in the callback for the event that will cause the Button to be enabled.

---

Also, the right code should be:

```
self.x = Button(self.dialog, text="Download", state=DISABLED, command=self.download)
self.x.pack(side=LEFT)
```

The method `pack` in `Button(...).pack()` returns `None`, and you are assigning it to `self.x`.  You actually want to assign the return value of `Button(...)` to `self.x`, and then, in the following line, use `self.x.pack()`.

Comment: It should be added that this code would go in the callback for the event that will cause the button to be enabled.

Comment: I tried got the error:
    self.x['state'] = 'enabled'
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Comment: it's better practice to use NORMAL than 'normal'

Answer (score 8):

I think a quick way to change the options of a widget is using the `configure` method.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
self.x.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I am not sure why the syntax is different, But it was extremely frustrating trying every combination of activate, inactive, deactivated, disabled, etc. In lower case upper case in quotes out of quotes in brackets out of brackets etc.  Well, here's the winning combination for me, for some reason.. different than everyone else?

```
import tkinter

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        butts = tkinter.Button(text = "add line", state="disabled")
        butts.grid()

def main():  
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = App()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yours is different because you did not import the constants from tkinter, `from tkinter import *` This will import DISABLED and other constants, otherwise `tkinter.DISABLED` will work the same.