# How to disable a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I click a button a new button displays but I want the previous clicked button to be disabled.

```
import tkinter as tk

def newbutton():  
    newbtn = tk.Button(app, text = "New Window button")
    newbtn.pack() 

app = tk.Tk()
buttonExample = tk.Button(app, text="Create new window", command=newbutton)
buttonExample.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Configure the previous `tk.Button`'s state to `tk.DISABLED`

Comment: Add `buttonExample.config(state=tk.DISABLED)` on the `newbutton()` function

Answer (score 1):

hi there have you tried to use the state command like this

buttonExample = tk.Button(app, text="Create new window", command=newbutton, state=DISABLED)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a very simple function that can disable a button

```
def disableButton(my_button):
    my_button.config(state='disabled')
```

There is already a post on stack talking about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046743/how-to-change-tkinter-button-state-from-disabled-to-normal)